Is this equivalent circuit transform involving resistors valid?

I was wondering whether this transform is valid
The resistance between ST3 and ST4
$$R_{S34} = \frac{(R_1+R_2)(R_3 +R_4)}{R_1+R_2+R_3+R_4}$$
The resistance between ST1 and ST2
$$R_{S12} = \frac{(R_1+R_3)(R_2 +R_4)}{R_1+R_2+R_3+R_4}$$
This leaves two resistors but no center connection for ST_12 and ST_34. To get around this I divide both resistors by two and connect the intersections:
$$R_8 = R_9 = \frac{R_{12}}{2}$$
$$R_6 = R_7 = \frac{R_{34}}{2}$$
Is this just wishful thinking?

The problem is under-constrained. If you apply a voltage across ST3 and ST4 what voltage would you expect to see at ST1 and ST2? And does that matter?

no star-delta transformation only works for 3 points. so for a general case of arbitrary resistors this will not work.  (e.g. if you short circuit st1-st3 and measure resistance betweem st2 and st4 it will not be the same).
